# How to give input files as loop inside perl script?

Tags: perl

I am using the script below to compare two files: `UEDP35.txt` and `BB_UEDP35.txt`. This script works well if I give inputs manually but now I need something more.

Inside one folder I have a number of files like `UEDP35.txt`. for eg: `UEDP1.txt`, `UEDP2.txt`, `UEDP3.txt` etc. Similarly there is another set of files like `BB_UEDP35.txt` e.g. `BB_UEDP1.txt`, `BB_UEDP2.txt`, `BB_UEDP3.txt` etc. `UEDP` is common in both files names.

If there is a pair with matching UEDP numbers then I want to give those two files as inputs to the script. If any differences are found while comparing them then they have to be written into another new file. This has to be done as loop.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open AIN, "<UEDP35.txt ";
open BIN, "<BB_UEDP35.csv";

my %seen;
while (<ain>) {
  my $v = (split(/,/))[0];
  $seen{$v}++;
}

while (<bin>) {
  my $v = (split)[0];
  print "$vn" if not $seen{substr($v, 0, 5)};
}

close AIN;
close BIN;

ls -1 UEDP* | while read line; do f1=echo $line | cut -f1 -d'.' ; f2=ls -1 BB_UEDP* | grep $f1;f3=echo $line | cut -f1; ./test.sh $f3 $f2;done
```

Example: I have two files: `A.txt` and `B.txt`. In file `A.txt`, the first file having a number with five digits. In file `B.txt` the whole number is given. If that first five digit of File `A.txt` doesn't match with the second file `B.txt` then I need to print the numbers in `B.txt` to another file.

A.txt

```
81270,UEDP35

81274,UEDP35

87562,UEDP35

89537,UEDP35

90050,UEDP35
```

B.txt

```
8127047667

8756209276

9956176149

8127463873

8953713146

9935805068
```

Here `A.txt` is `UEDP35.txt` and `B.txt` is `BB_UEDP35.txt`.

Comment: 1st off: post code which compiles. 2nd: if your only problem is that your having multiple files in the form `UEDP` followed by a number, then whats wrong with a simple `for ( 1..n)` loop?

Comment: @pavel. I am not getting. I use something like this. ls -1 UEDP* | while read line; do f1=`echo $line | cut -f1 -d'.'` ; f2=`ls -1 BB_UEDP* | grep $f1`;f3=`echo $line | cut -f1`; ./test.sh $f3 $f2;done
to give as input.

Comment: again, what's your actual code? Please put it in your question, not (unreadable) in comments; what you're showing in your comment is some sh-code, not perl...

Comment: You should probably spend some more time trying to explain what exactly what you are trying to do. You want to compare `UEDP35.txt` with `BB_UEDP35.txt`, I gather, but then you say `If any different occur` export to a different file. Different how? `UEDP35` vs `BB_UEDQ35`? Difference inside the file? "Different" is a very *wide* perspective.

Comment: @TLP Sorry for confusing. I am new here. That script will take care. The output which comes out that script that i want to export into another file.

Comment: @parvel. inside that test.sh only this code is present.. the one which is mentioned before is how i am using now to give input file to that perl script. Half shell and Half perl. But i feel if i can able to do that in same script it will be better

Comment: @Mike You are probably trying to clarify, but actually you didn't say anything new. "The script will take care" is just gibberish. Some advice: Don't try to describe it, *show* it. Use examples.

Comment: @Mike: It is good that you have shown the contents of the input files, but please show what *output* you want to see from these two sample files. I need to see what you mean by sending the numbers in `B.txt` to another file. Does it matter if there are numbers in `A.txt` that don't appear in `B.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $bb_uedp_file (<BB_UEDP*>) {
  if ($bb_uedp_file =~ /BB_UEDP(\d+)/) {
    my $uedp_file = "UEDP$1.txt";
    open AIN, "<$uedp_file"    or die($uedp_file);
    open BIN, "<$bb_uedp_file" or die($bb_uedp_file);
    # ...  rest of the script ...
    close AIN;
    close BIN;
  }
}
```